# How do I build a diagramming application in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, drawing, diagram

I want to write a GUI seating application that allows users to draw and annotate simple "maps" of seating areas.

The end result would probably look something a little like Visio, but specifically for manipulating my "seating" data model rather than producing files.

In Java-land, there's the Graphical Editing Framework (GEF) -- is there anything like this in the .NET space? Should I just use System.Drawing.Drawing2D primitives and handle it all myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is product from [Nevron](http://www.nevron.com/Products.DiagramFor.NET.Overview.aspx). It is paid but doing it all yourself will take lot of time and effort.

[Open Diagram](https://github.com/prepare/opendiagram) and [EasyDiagram.net](http://easydiagram.codeplex.com/) are available at [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com). Be sure to download and look into their code.

Comment: Most links are dead.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Netron Library](http://www.orbifold.net/default/?page_id=1272) for diagramming. It is open source and uses GDI+.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [NShape](https://github.com/dataweb-GmbH/NShape). It is an open source diagramming framework written in C# and quite powerful. Its controls are WinForms controls but you can also use it for WPF.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the DSL Toolkit from the Visual Studio SDK. It allows you to create a graphical DSL designer by first creating a domain model, and then creating the graphical notation that will allow users to create or edit instances of that model.

You may very well be able to create a graphical notation that looks like a seating area. This would allow your users to not only "diagram", but to produce a file containing a filled-in domain model of what was diagrammed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out our [MetaDraw](http://www.bennet-tec.com/btProducts/MetaDraw/MetaDraw.htm) component.
MetaDraw is designed to make applications like this easy.
MetaDraw will support a background image and an annotation layer
You can put users into a variety of editing modes - Lines, Curves, Text, Shapes, etc.
Every drawn element is distinct - just like in Visio, so you can allow users to select objects and move them around or resize them.   Every object can have multiple hidden tags ( like seat numbers or database record pointers ).  You can recognize which objects users select ( for instance take some action when user clicks seat 22 ) .  You can dynamically modify propertie by code - such as searching for seat 22 and changing it's fill color.   Of course you can also scroll, zoom, print, save to a variety of formats and more.